# Does Twitter support the 2-legged oAuth protocol?

Tags: oauth, twitter

The oAuth protocol comes in two flavors, 3-legged and 2-legged protocols. The 3-legged one is about delegating user access rights to an application and is the one that gets the most attention on the web. The 2-legged version is used to authenticate an application against a service provider (Twitter in my case) with no specific user involved.

In my application I need read only access to publicly available information, but at higher rate than the one available to unauthenticated request. There is no need for me to authenticate as a specific Twitter user.

Does Twitter support the 2-legged version of oAuth?

Boaz

PS. The whitelisting alternative is an overkill for me and I rather not wait for the approval process.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an access token for a single user following these instructions: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token

Comment: I assume, if the app is read/write these tokens would be read/write also. I've got two apps registered, PithyTwits & PithyTwits-RO. The second one is read only. I just logged into it and captured the tokens manually. When a user isn't authed the app logs in read only as @PithyTwits. This gives access to the @PithyTwits TL, lists, and search functions. When they decide to auth, tokens are dumped and they auth against the read/write app. Am I correct in assuming there is no way to accomplish this read/write vs read only functionality without using 2 apps?

Comment: Disregard, I figured it out. I need to get the PithyTwits-RO oauth single tokens. This way when the app is operating read only, it is logged in as the app, and not as any specific @ name. All functionality should still exist.

Comment: Just looked closer at the keys. It does appear they are @user keys for the application account owner. Which does make sense. I just need to stick with the read only application.